# How to express that you can understand the English that someone spoke?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

"I can read English", "I can speak English", or "I can write English" are all correct uses of the word "English".

But is "I can listen to English" correct English?
Or should I say "I can hear English"?
Are there better ways to say that?

I want to know how to express that you can understand the English that someone has spoken.

Comment: Where I live in the SW USA it is often "Habla ingles". :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But is "I can listen to English" correct English?
>   Or should I say "I can hear English"?
>   Are there better ways to say that?

First up, "I can listen to English" is correct English. But you are trying to say that you can *understand* English that is said aloud. Just by saying "listen" doesn't necessarily mean that you *understand* spoken English. I can listen to Greek, but still not understand, because I don't know Greek.

Some better ways to say it are:

> I can understand spoken English
>   I can comprehend spoken English
>   I can understand English that is spoken.
>   I can understand English that is said aloud.

Edit:

If understanding is not really necessary, just hearing and being able to listen to the language, you could try:

> I can catch the English language most of the time.
>   I can make out spoken English.
>   I can take in spoken English

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Understanding English is not necessary. I want to know how to say that you have an ability to `clearly` listen to English. In that case "I can listen to English" and "I can hear English" are correct?

Comment: @js_: unless you are deaf you can *hear* English (as long as someone is speaking it!). *Listen* has a attention connotation to it, so if you *listen* to something you are paying attention to it. It does not necessarily mean you understand it. The edited question gives some nicer options to say that.

Comment: @js_: What you're looking for is probably something along the lines of "I have good English listening comprehension", which is more specific to how well you are at picking up spoken English. It's less focused on how well you understand English, and more on how well your brain can handle/sort English audio.

Answer (score 7):

I think the phrase you're looking for is contained in your question: "I can understand English."

**Edit:** after comments by Malvolio and Peter Shor, I agree that "I can understand *spoken* English" is more clear than my original version, especially if you're illiterate in the target language, or if for some other reason it's important to distinguish between the two.

I use a similar phrase myself—I studied French in high school and college and spent a few months in Paris, but I haven't had many opportunities to practice in the last fifteen years. I can still understand it fairly well if it's spoken slowly, but I find it very difficult to express my own thoughts. Therefore, I *understand* French (a little), but I don't *speak* French.

Comment: I think the OP was distinguish between the language as written and it as spoken.  For a language with a written forms radically different from yours (consider Mandarin), you may be able to understood it as spoken perfectly well but be completely illiterate.

Comment: I still think *understand* is the best fit. In fact, I can say (honestly) that I understand some Mandarin, though I've only been learning for a few months and can read only a few characters.

Comment: I think the right thing to say, if you want to distinguish between reading and listening, is *I can understand spoken English*.

Comment: Fair enough; that certainly clarifies the matter.

Comment: @Nicholas Thanks for your answer and comments.
But I think "I can read Englsh" and "I understand written English" are different.
Many people can read English without understanding.
Sometimes I also can read difficult English without understanding.
So it is possible to be able to clearly listen to English without understanding.
I need audio version of "I can read Englsh" not of "I understand written English".
I'm an English learner and can not listen to English clearly at all.

Comment: As Thursagen says, "listen to" would not carry the meaning of understanding what you hear, so maybe that's the phrase you want. However, it doesn't really make sense to me. Similarly, if you "can read English" but you don't "understand written English," then I would argue that you *can't* read English—you can just look at the written words and maybe sound them out. You might say, "I can listen to spoken English," and that doesn't mean "I understand spoken English"—but anyone who isn't deaf can listen to spoken English without necessarily understanding it, so why bother saying so?

Comment: @Nicholas Thanks for your reply. I think you're right.
Read/write/speak includes meaning of understanding.
And "listen to" or "hear" don't include meaning of understanding.
That is the reason why "I can read/write/speak English" are normal to say but "I can listen to English" is not normal.
Why "listen to" or "hear" don't include meaning of understanding?
Are there words which means "listen to or hear English and understand it"?

Comment: @js_, *"It's easy/difficult for me to understand spoken English"* is probably the clearest way to say that, when listening to English, it is clear/not clear to you what is being said.